# VBA code to only select Range, currently getting multiple errors

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code including an automated insert next row if a specific text field is selected.

Someone helped me out with a starting point with the code. The only problem is when I enter the code and tab to the next cell to enter data it give me a"Runtime 91 error".

I am thinking because the Code does not give a specific range that it is erroring out on me.. I want to enter data still without having to hit end when I get an error.

**The original code reads:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Columns(2)
    If Intersect(rng, Target).Value = "Y" Then             
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

End Sub
```

**My edit was :**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A30")

    If rng("A1:A30").Value = "Y" Then
        Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If

End Sub
```

:which I am still getting an error.

Can someone help clarify this for me?

Comment: You need to loop through the cells in the range: you can't compare an entire range to "Y" in  `If rng("A1:A30").Value = "Y"`

Comment: Can you give me an example? Sorry new to VBA and doing the best I can to learn it .

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare a multi-cell range to "Y."

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A30"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim cell as Range
    For Each cell in rng
        If cell.Value = "Y" Then
            cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```